# How to disable systemd logging to console?

Tags: linux, logging, systemd

I am using systemd in Debian Jessie, and systemd outputs lots of messages during system boot

```
Jul 27 00:13:18 Rastes systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 27 00:13:18 Rastes systemd[1]: Failed to start Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jul 27 00:13:18 Rastes systemd[1]: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service entered failed state.
Jul 28 00:13:58 Rastes systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 28 00:13:58 Rastes systemd[1]: Failed to start Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jul 28 00:13:58 Rastes systemd[1]: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service entered failed state.
```

I have tried to add kernel arguments to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT like

```
systemd.log_target=/dev/null systemd.journald.forward_to_console=0 systemd.default_standard_output=null systemd.default_standard_error=null
```

but systemd continue to output logging to console.

How to switch off logging into console? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can turn off `ForwardToConsole=` in `journald.conf` (http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html)

Comment: are you using plymouth or any boot splash?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off ForwardToConsole= in journald.conf (freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html)